# How to set up a pipeline for DataFlex open source project in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: windows, azure-devops, open-source, azure-pipelines, dataflex

I would like to set up a build pipeline for the [DFUnit](https://github.com/olaeld/DFUnit) (unit testing framework for DataFlex) open source project, using Microsoft's offer of free build pipelines for open source projects.

However, installing the DataFlex build environment may prove hard to script. Can I set up a VM? Are there any other examples of comparable setups in a Windows environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the free agents, [but you can setup your own build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops). Once you get this setup, you have access to all of the pipeline tasks and reporting capabilities.